# Webusb Api cannot open the device

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to open one of my semiconductor device using webusb api. but after selecting the device i am unable to use the open function on the device

```
await navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters:[]})
await device.open()
```

i am using these two lines as of now to open the device and I also checked the error in chrome:// device.logs it says

> [11:44:12]
> SetupDiGetDeviceProperty({{A45C254E-DF1C-4EFD-8020-67D146A850E0}, 6})
> failed: Element not found. (0x490)